# How can i retrieve Checkboxes (allow multiple selections) as checkboxes values to a custom webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a Checkboxes (allow multiple selections) field in a list and i would like to show the values as checkbox selected/unslected  in a custom webpart(Using SharePoint Designer.
Currently i show them as text.
e.g Options :Red,Yellow
But what want is Options : CheckboxSelected-Red,CheckboxUnSelected-Blue,CheckboxSelected-Yellow

When i Format as checkbox what i get is:

Which just shows a checkbox with no text and nothing..

Any ideas.I want something similar when i select the item in Edit View.
Thankks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code?  It appears it didn't come through.

Comment: Yeah it didn't and thanks for the reply.
I have been able to get the checkbox values by formating the node as list for field.
Chrs